# How will I be able to compare two button presses from a choice of three?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have 3 buttons

b1
b2
b3

I want to now have these buttons be pressed in turns. 
So turn one I press and turn 2 another person presses. 
So after turn two, I will compare the names of the buttons.

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {
        b1.setEnabled(false);
        if (!b1.isEnabled() && !b2.isEnabled()) {
            //computeWinner(b1.getText(), b2.getText());
        } else if(!b1.isEnabled() && !b3.isEnabled()) {
            //computeWinner(b1.getText(), b2.getText());
        }
    }
});
```

This was what I thought would work, but there are many things wrong with this,
First, since I disable the buttons the second user always has one less option. and second the if statements do not seem to work? how should I compare the
JButton b3 = new JButton ("hello"); <- hello lable of the buttons?

EDIT: 
I was able to successfully compare the two buttons. Now my only problem is that for the second player one of the buttons are disabled(how can I capture the first button press and the second without disabling them?). And that after the comparison I don't know how to reset the board to go again. (for a set number of loops.)

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will print the label of the button which has been pressed. I hope, you should be able to proceed from here. Feel free to let me know if you face any further issue.

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
      System.out.println(actionEvent.getActionCommand());
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, my comparing worked this way, however, I am still facing the problem with the button press (it disables so the other player cant press one of the buttons). and to be able to keep pressing the buttons after each comparison.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

1. Store the buttons in a `map<Integer, String>`.  the integer would be a count for keeping track of pushes.  The string would be the actionCommand of the button pressed.
2. Store the button actionCommands in a list or array.

In either of the above you can provide appropriate logic to compare the buttons and then reset the arrays or map and count.

Note:  The actionCommand defaults to the button label unless it explicitly set.

Comment: hi, thank you for responding. Im really new to java so im not really sure I should use "map" since I haven't been introduced to it yet. I was able to successfully get compare two buttons. Now my only problem is that for the second player one of the buttons are disabled. And that after the comparison I don't know how to reset the board to go again. (for a set number of loops.) - I will edit this into my question.

Comment: I modified my answer a bit.  A third alternative is to use different action listeners for each button.